# ERROR: database is being accessed by other users DETAIL: There are 24 other sessions using the database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to drop a database, but when I try to drop it, I get this error:

> ERROR: database "mydb" is being accessed by other users
>   DETAIL: There are 24 other sessions using the database.

I just want to drop it so I can restore it from a backup.  Based on another thread I tried this:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb FROM public;

SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'mydb';
```

This didn't work.  I still get error message there are sessions.

In the database are 2 schemas, `public` and `hangfire`, so I am not sure if that is causing the issue.

This is my local database, no one else is using it.  Why is it not dropping?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

solution was:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'mydb';

SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'mydb';

DROP DATABASE mydb;
```

Comment: This solution was helpful to me! Thanks!

Comment: Getting error "permission denied for table pg_database." Is this the name of my database? If so, what is 'mydb'? I thought *that* was the name of my database.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you still got some connections is probably that these users have been granted explicit permissions on the database.

In all likelihood it is the owner of the database. You'd have to revoke the connect privilege from the owner explicitly.