# Postgresql error database does not exist however it exists when listing the databases

Tags: postgresql, drop-database

When I drop the database I have an error that it doesn't exist however when I list the databases I can see it.
Here are the steps I am following:

- sudo -u postgres psql
- postgres=# \l
- postgres=# DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydbname;

NOTICE:  database "mydbname" does not exist, skipping
DROP DATABASE

```
                                    List of databases
        Name        |     Owner     | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |     Access privileges
--------------------+---------------+----------+---------+---------+----------------------------
 mydbname           | postgres      | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres              +
                    |               |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres     +
                    |               |          |         |         | cryptouser=CTc/postgres
```

Comment: I found the solution in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471160/error-database-is-being-accessed-by-other-users-detail-there-are-24-other-sess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: database is being accessed by other users DETAIL: There are 24 other sessions using the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471160/error-database-is-being-accessed-by-other-users-detail-there-are-24-other-sess)

Comment: The linked question describes a completely different problem than "database does not exist"